# Generate git merge commit reference in Bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, devops

In one of our Jenkins jobs to checkout into pull requests, we are relying on an implementation detail of Bitbucket, namely the Pull request merge commit, which could be accessed using `pull-requests/*/merge`.

Bitbucket has [dropped support for 3 way merge](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-12284?focusedCommentId=2389584&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2389584), and therefore it is not possible for us to run:

```
        if (isPR(config.BRANCH)) {
            echo 'In PR type commit'
            PR_ID=parsePRId(config.BRANCH)
            TARGET_COMMIT="pull-requests/$PR_ID/merge"
            FROM_COMMIT="pull-requests/$PR_ID/from"
        } else {
            echo 'Non PR type commit'
            TARGET_COMMIT=config.BRANCH
            FROM_COMMIT=config.BRANCH
        }

        // Fetch hash of from commit for marking build status
        sh "git fetch origin $FROM_COMMIT"
        result.branch = config.BRANCH
        result.fromCommitId = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD").trim()
        result.fromCommitIdShort = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse --short FETCH_HEAD").trim()

        try {
            // Checkout target commit
            sh """
                git fetch origin $TARGET_COMMIT && \
                git checkout -f FETCH_HEAD
            """
            result.targetCommitId = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD").trim();
            result.targetCommitIdShort = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse --short FETCH_HEAD").trim();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            result.targetCommitId = null
            result.targetCommitIdShort = null
        }
```

Are there any alternatives to doing this? The end goal is to checkout the pull request to build/deploy microservices in the monorepo.

Comment: The way they phrased this ("dropped support for 3-way merge") is not good as it implies things that aren't true: you can still *do your own* `git merge`. It's a lot more work now though because now you have to see whether that merge works. I wouldn't want to do this in Jenkins/Groovy (though a lot of that is because I think these are terrible systems), but it certainly should be *possible*. Meanwhile, the way you've phrased *your* final question ("check out the pull request to deploy") is actually *far easier*. Just check out the commit!

Comment: How you do that in Jenkins, using Bitbucket specific names, is purely a Jenkins-and-Bitbucket issue, but it's probably just a matter of parsing `refs/pull-requests/<pr-id>/head`. I'm guessing a bit on the `head` as I don't use Bitbucket.

Comment: @torek thanks for taking the time to write. Could you please point me to how to "simulate" this merge, and get a commit ID that I can use?

Comment: You don't so much *simulate* the merge as, quite literally, run `git merge` and see if that works. Jenkins already has a clone, so perhaps you can do that in the Jenkins clone, but perhaps you should do that in an extra clone for Jenkins-specific reasons (whatever those might be) and then if and only if it works, bring the new commit back. Or perhaps you can add a working tree with `git worktree add` and try the merge there.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the issue by creating doing a heavy checkout. This still needs to be tested better.

```
           if (isPR(config.BRANCH)) {
                echo 'In PR type commit'
                PR_ID=parsePRId(config.BRANCH)
                FROM_COMMIT="pull-requests/$PR_ID/from"
                /* this is needed because bitbucket dropped support for PR merge refs 
                    more info in https://jira.dna.fi/browse/CXA-1509
                */
                sh """
                    git checkout origin/master && \
                    git checkout -b interim && \
                    git merge "origin/${env.CHANGE_BRANCH}"
                """
                def interimCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse HEAD").trim();

                TARGET_COMMIT = interimCommit
            }
```